# How to set the background of the A QtWidget the same as the QTableWidget Row

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I have a QTableWidget in which I have set `alternating colors` for each row.

In the QTableWidget, the last 2 columns of each row contains a `QPushButton` widget. What I want is basically the background color of the QPushButton to be set the same as the background color of the row.

To achieve this, I managed to use the `Mod` function of Mathematics and checked whether my row is even or odd, **at the time of setting data in the QTableWidget**

```
 if (tablerow % 2 == 0):
                edit_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: none")
                delete_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: none")
            else:
                edit_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); border-style: none")
                delete_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); border-style: none")
```

This is the complete function that is getting the data and setting it on QTableWidget,

```
 def get_section_data(self):
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor()
        Subquery = "Select section_name from tbl_section"
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)

        numcols = len(mycursor.fetchall()[0])
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        numrows = len(mycursor.fetchall())
        self.ui.section_table.setRowCount(numrows)
        self.ui.section_table.setColumnCount(numcols+2)
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        tablerow = 0
        for row in mycursor.fetchall():
            tablecol = 0
            delete_button = QPushButton()
            icon = QIcon()
            icon.addFile(u":/icons/icons/Delete-button.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
            delete_button.setIcon(icon)
            index = PySide2.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.ui.section_table.model().index(tablerow, tablecol))
            self.ui.section_table.setCellWidget(tablerow, 2, delete_button)
            delete_button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, index=index: self.on_section_table_click())
            edit_button = QPushButton()
            icon = QIcon()
            icon.addFile(u":/icons/icons/edit-button.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
            edit_button.setIcon(icon)
            index = PySide2.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.ui.section_table.model().index(tablerow, tablecol))
            self.ui.section_table.setCellWidget(tablerow, 1, edit_button)
            edit_button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, index=index: self.on_section_edit_click())
            if (tablerow % 2 == 0):
                edit_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: none")
                delete_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: none")
            else:
                edit_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); border-style: none")
                delete_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); border-style: none")
            while tablecol < numcols:
                self.ui.section_table.setItem(tablerow, tablecol, PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[tablecol])))
                tablecol += 1
            tablerow += 1
        self.ui.section_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(PySide2.QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

The problem, however, occurs when I perform Searching on this Data. The function for the searching is as follows,

```
def SectionSearch(self):
        name = self.ui.search_section_text.text().lower()
        for row in range(self.ui.section_table.rowCount()):
            item = self.ui.section_table.item(row, 0)
            self.ui.section_table.setRowHidden(row, name not in item.text().lower())
```

So, it is hiding every row that doesn't match the Searched Item. Problem is, now the arrangement of Sections change and due to that, row color also gets affected. For example, check the following image,

[image]

As you can see, the buttons now have a different background color than the Row background color.

I believe that this problem is solvable if I somehow manage to give the background color to QPushButton the same background color which the row in which it is associated with has. Can anyone tell me how can anyone achieve this?

Comment: You don't actually need a button just for that, you can use an item delegate or just connect to the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal of the view, and set an icon for the index. That said, just set the stylesheet of the button with a `transparent` background, or eventually set a transparent color for the `Button` role in the palette of the buttons.

Comment: Thank you! That helped and solved the whole issue! :)